# Is it possible to call methods from specific objects using a variable?

Tags: python, oop, variables

I've been wondering this for a time now and it seems like something Python *would* have, but is it possible to call the same method from different using code similar to this?

Here's the class I'm using to test this:

```
class Test():
   def __init__(self,foo):
      self.foo = foo
   def method_a():
      print(self.foo)
```

And here's the running code:

```
import classTest
object1 = classTest.Test("Unn")
object2 = classTest.Test("Tss")
runThis = input("Type in either object1 or object2:")
runThis.method_a()
```

I get this:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'method_a'

Have I done something wrong? Or does Python lack that functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your objects in a dictionary:

```
objects = {}
objects['object1'] = classTest.Test("Unn")
objects['object2'] = classTest.Test("Tss")
runThis = input("Type in either object1 or object2:")
objects[runThis].method_a()
```

You can also access the module globals with the [`globals()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), which gives you a dictionary too, but *most of the time* you want to use a dedicated dictionary instead.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I can think of many ways to apply this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `globals` to access your variables by name:

```
globals()[runThis].method_a()
```

Answer (score 1):

Also it might be helpful in some case.

```
import gc
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, Test):
        print obj
```

Comment: But only if you need to find instances of `Test` in a debug session. `gc.get_objects()` loops through **all** tracked objects in an application (anything that can be part of a circular dependency).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
import classTest
object1 = classTest.Test("Unn")
object2 = classTest.Test("Tss")
runThis = eval(raw_input("Type in either object1 or object2:"), globals())
runThis.method_a()
```